# Convert JPG to PDF using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument, cfpdf

Here's my current attempt to convert JPG to PDF using ColdFusion.  I used cfdocument because it seemed easy to use:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="jpgtopdf" mimetype="image/jpeg" srcfile="#myfile#"  pageheight="11" pagewidth="8.5">
</cfdocument>
```

Unfortunately this reduces the resolution to 72 DPI, destroying the details in the JPG.  I would like to preserve the original JPG resolution.  What is the best way to convert JPG to PDF?

--

EDIT: When I put `<img>` inside `<cfdocument>` it just produces a blank document.  I believe this happens because, for security, `#myfile#` is outside the webroot.  Fortunately, this led me to this answer: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4813587/dynamic-pdf-cfdocument-cfcontent-image-email-attachement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813587/dynamic-pdf-cfdocument-cfcontent-image-email-attachement) which indeed allows the conversion to be done with higher resolution.  Here is my new code which seems to produce 300 DPI:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="jpgtopdf" pageheight="11" pagewidth="8.5">
  <cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#myfile#">
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: This should help - http://developersblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/hi-res-backgrounds-in-cf-pdf-generation/

Comment: It might be worth a shot to put an img tag inside your cfdocument block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF">
    <img src="path to the image" width="1024px">
</cfdocument>
```

On CF11 it gives nice result.

Comment: This got me on the right track, except that I had to use `<cfimage>` instead of `<img>`.  Thanks!